# How to use xfail in pytest in parameterized fixture when pytest.param is an elemenent in a tuple?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

This works

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize( "expected",  
    [  
        pytest.param(42, marks=pytest.mark.xfail(reason="some bug")),  
    ],)  
def test_func(expected):  
    assert 123  == expected
```

output is

```
test_xfail_demo_1.py::test_func[42] XFAIL (some bug)
========== 1 xfailed in 0.07s ==========
```

but this one does not

```
import pytest
def someFunc():
    return 1

def someOtherFunc():
    return 123

@pytest.mark.parametrize( "expected",  
    [  
        (1, pytest.param(42, marks=pytest.mark.xfail(reason="some bug"))),  
    ],)  
def test_func(expected):  
    assert someFunc() == expected[0]
    assert someOtherFunc()  == expected[1]
```

The error I got is

```
>       assert someOtherFunc()  == expected[1]
E       AssertionError: assert 123 == ParameterSet(values=(42,), 

marks=(MarkDecorator(mark=Mark(name='xfail', args=(), kwargs={'reason': 'some bug'})),), id=None)
path/to/test_xfail_demo_2.py:10: AssertionError
==================== short test summary info ===============
FAILED path/to/test_xfail_demo_2.py::test_func[expected0] - AssertionError: assert 123 == ParameterSet(values=(42,), marks=(MarkDecorator(mark=Mark(name='xfail', args=(), kwargs={'reason': 'some bug'})),), id=None)
============== 1 failed in 0.09s =====
```

The reason I want expected to be a tuple is because I have multiple assert in a single test function, and I want to pass in all the expected values as a tuple or list, but mark only some of the list elements to be xfail or skip.

Comment: Didn't you mean to write `pytest.param((1, 42), marks=pytest.mark.xfail(reason="some bug"))`?

Comment: No that is not a typo, yes I have seen that pattern in some tutorials, but here I just want expected var to be values on the right side of = 

the assert `1 == expected[0]` are simplified examples, my real use case is `assert someFunc()  == expected[0]` and `assert someOtherFunc() == expected[1]` ...

Comment: I'm not sure how that is supposed to work. Your parameter is a tuple, and it is either skipped or not - I can't see how marking _a part of the parameter_ as skipped should work. I'm probably missing something... Maybe you can elaborate a bit more in the question.

Comment: I noticed that you edited the question, but this doesn't make it more clear to me. Do you expect that one of the asserts inside your test is skipped that way? That certainly cannot work this way.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen oh yes, that is my goal - one of the asserts inside your test is skipped that way.  Maybe I misunderstood how xfail should be used then. If I have multiple asserts in a single test function,  and the test function takes 2 or more lazy fixutres, and pass in expected tuple to multiple asserts, what is the recommended way of writing it ( so code is not repeated) ?

Comment: Either split the asserts into separate tests, or add a parameter check in the test itself, if only a part of the test shall not be executed.